# XSLT to convert XML table to HTML table with align char attribute getting error in saxon8.jar

Tags: xml, xslt

Please suggest, how to solve the error which is occurring when XSLT run with **saxon8.jar**, but same XSLT and inputs are providing right results with **saxon9he.jar** as given below Table image.

In XSLT 91, 97 and 104th lines are having some errors as given below error image. Please suggest, how to solve these errors. Given XSLT script is bit bigger, but posted here to show the complete result.

**XML:**

```
<article>
<table id="t1"><label>Table 1</label><caption>Table caption</caption><tgroup cols="4"><colspec colnum="1" colname="col1"/><colspec colnum="2" colname="col2"/><colspec colnum="3" colname="col3"/><colspec colnum="4" colname="col4"/>
<thead>
<row><entry>No</entry><entry namest="col2" nameend="col4">Cells</entry></row>
<row rowsep="1"><entry></entry><entry>106</entry><entry>406</entry><entry>107</entry></row></thead>

<tbody>
<row><entry>1</entry><entry align="char" char="." namest="col2" nameend="col3">821.23</entry><entry align="char" char=".">1115.6</entry></row>
<row><entry>2</entry><entry align="char" char=".">13.1</entry><entry align="char" char=".">1.3</entry><entry align="char" char=".">9</entry></row>
<row><entry>3</entry><entry align="char" char=".">14.5</entry><entry align="char" char=".">2120.9</entry><entry align="char" char=".">7.8</entry></row>
<row><entry>4</entry><entry align="char" char=".">18.9</entry><entry align="char" char=".">20.4</entry><entry align="char" char=".">22.356</entry></row>
</tbody></tgroup></table>
</article>
```

**XSLT:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
xmlns:mml="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML" 
exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
version="2.0">
<xsl:output method="html"/>

<xsl:template match="table"><!--Table -->
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="id">
            <xsl:choose>
                <xsl:when test="number(tgroup/@cols) gt 4"><xsl:text>table-dc</xsl:text></xsl:when>
                <xsl:otherwise><xsl:text>table-sc</xsl:text></xsl:otherwise>
            </xsl:choose>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <Table border="1">
            <xsl:attribute name="class">
                <xsl:choose>
                    <xsl:when test="@frame"><xsl:value-of select="concat('table-', @frame)"/></xsl:when>
                    <xsl:otherwise>table</xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
            </xsl:attribute>
            <a><xsl:attribute name="name"><xsl:value-of select="@id"/></xsl:attribute></a>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="caption"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="source"/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="tgroup"/>
        </Table>
    </div>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="thead|tbody"><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row"><!-- Table row -->
    <tr><xsl:apply-templates/></tr>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="entry"><!--Table cells -->
    <xsl:variable name="var1"><xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(@namest, 'col'))"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="var2"><xsl:value-of select="number(substring-after(@nameend, 'col'))"/></xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="varColSpan">
        <xsl:value-of select="(number($var2)-number($var1))+1"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:if test="ancestor::thead">
        <th>
            <xsl:if test="@morerows"><xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="@morerows+1"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if><!--RowSpan-->
            <xsl:if test="@namest"><!--Col span-->
                <xsl:attribute name="colspan"><xsl:value-of select="$varColSpan"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@align"><xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat('text-align:', @align)"/></xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="number(@rowsep) gt 0">
                <xsl:attribute name="class">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="number(@rowsep) gt 0">rowsep</xsl:when>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </th>
    </xsl:if>
    <xsl:if test="ancestor::tbody">
        <td>
            <xsl:if test="@morerows"><xsl:attribute name="rowspan"><xsl:value-of select="@morerows+1"/></xsl:attribute></xsl:if><!--RowSpan-->
            <xsl:if test="@namest"><!--Col span-->
                <xsl:attribute name="colspan"><xsl:value-of select="$varColSpan"/></xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:if test="@align"><xsl:attribute name="style" select="concat('text-align:', @align)"/></xsl:if>

            <xsl:if test="@align='char' and  @char and not(ancestor::table//tbody//entry/@morerows)">
                <xsl:call-template name="tempAlignCHAR">
                    <xsl:with-param name="paramLen" select="if(contains(., @char)) then string-length(substring-before(., @char)) else string-length(.)"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="paramPos" select="position()"/>
                    <xsl:with-param name="paramChar" select="@char"/>
                </xsl:call-template>
            </xsl:if>
            <xsl:apply-templates/>
        </td>
    </xsl:if>
</xsl:template>

    <xsl:template name="tempAlignCHAR">
        <xsl:param name="paramLen"/>
        <xsl:param name="paramPos"/>
        <xsl:param name="paramChar"/>

        <xsl:variable name="varPresentPosition">
            <xsl:value-of select="number($paramPos) 
                + 
                sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend/number(substring-after(., 'col')))
                 - 
                sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest/number(substring-after(., 'col')))"/><!--Error1-->
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="var1">
            <xsl:for-each select="ancestor::tbody/row/entry[number(position()) 
                + sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend/number(substring-after(., 'col'))) 
                - sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest/number(substring-after(., 'col'))) = 
                $varPresentPosition][@align='char' and @char]/string-length(substring-before(., $paramChar))"><!--Error2-->
                <xsl:sort select="." order="descending"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()=1"><xsl:value-of select="number(.)"/></xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:variable>

        <xsl:variable name="var2"><xsl:value-of select="number($paramLen)"/></xsl:variable>
        <xsl:variable name="var3"><xsl:value-of select="number($var1)-number($var2)"/></xsl:variable>

        <font style="color:white">
            <xsl:for-each select="1 to $var3">
                <xsl:value-of select="'0'"/>
            </xsl:for-each>
        </font>

    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**HTML table with saxon9he.jar:**

[image]

**Error message for the same scripts with saxon8.jar:**
Run syntax: java -jar saxon8.jar CharAlign.xml CharAlign.xsl > CharAlign.html
[image]

Comment: As we can't know which like are marked as 91; 97 and 104. Can you highlight these specific lines?

Comment: @UsamaZafar, Error1, Error2, Error3 like comments are placed in XSLT.

Comment: Well, first of all, why do you have to use Saxon 8? It is a decade old (or older, depending on the exact version) and any version other than 8.9 never implemented the existing XSLT/XPath 2.0 standard but rather reflected working drafts. And of course, if you do use Saxon 8, then at least tell us the full version. As a try, you could replace expressions like `sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend/number(substring-after(., 'col')))` with `sum(for $a in preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend return number(substring-after($a, 'col')))`.

Comment: Not an answer, but your XSLT is correct. If this works with later Saxon versions but fails with 8, it's most likely a bug. Unless you've got some support contract that covers bug fixes in legacy versions, I think you'll be out of luck and will have to upgrade.

Comment: @MartinHonnen sir, thanks for very useful suggestion, while updating old version scripts, getting this error. One more suggestion required from you for '[@align='char' and @char]/string-length(substring-before(., $paramChar))', where i modified as '/string-length(for $a in . return text(substring-before($a, $paramChar)))"><!--Error2-->'. In above XSLT <!--Error2--> side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the old version of Saxon 8 does not support the use of e.g. `foo/function-call(.)` and you have to rewrite it as `for $f in foo return function-call($f)` so try to rewrite

```
ancestor::tbody/row/entry[number(position()) 
                + sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend/number(substring-after(., 'col'))) 
                - sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest/number(substring-after(., 'col'))) = 
                $varPresentPosition][@align='char' and @char]/string-length(substring-before(., $paramChar))
```

as

```
for $e in ancestor::tbody/row/entry[number(position()) 
                + sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@nameend/number(substring-after(., 'col'))) 
                - sum(preceding-sibling::entry/@namest/number(substring-after(., 'col'))) = 
                $varPresentPosition][@align='char' and @char] return string-length(substring-before($e, $paramChar))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Sir for very useful suggestion, now I got the required result. Plus one.

Answer (score 0):

The error message saying that the RH operand of "/" must be a node indicates that the Saxon version you are using implements some early working draft of XSLT 2.0 before the specification was changed: it's probably at least 10 years old. "saxon8.jar" actually could be any release from Saxon 8.0 to Saxon 8.9 covering a wide range of functionality changes. There is no reason to be using such an old release any more.